# Create a measure that converts minutes into hours

Tags: powerbi

My searching is weak so I didn't find anything that satisfied my need.

I have a dataset of work items. I have a lead time column present on each record. It is in minutes, and I want to create a measure that displays lead time in hours. I want that measure to be (in pseudo code):

lead time (hrs) = lead time / 60

I'm a Tableau user and am finding this difficult to do in Power BI. What is your advice?

Comment: If you are using a direct query, then here is a method:
1. Edit Query
2. In Power Query Editor find Add Column tab
3. Press Custom Column button
4. Here you can specify new column for example [lead time]/60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got an answer from the powerbi community. Here it is:

```
lead time (hrs) = SELECTEDVALUE(Dataset[lead time])/ 60
```

I hope this helps someone.